# Changing second vector to produce orthonormal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I have determined the following two vectors to be linearly independent. But how do I change $u_2$ so $u_1,u_2$ are orthonormal vectors?

My workings:

$u_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1  
\\0
\end{bmatrix}, $ $u_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1  
\\-1
\end{bmatrix}$ So, $(1)(-1)+(0)(1)=-1$thus these two vectors are linearly independent, but what can I change $u_2$ to make then orthonormal?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace that wouldn't work, since then $u_1 \cdot u_2 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, and in order for two vectors to be orthonormal they have to have a dot product of $0$.

Comment: Subtract the projection of $u_2$ onto $u_1$ from $u_2$ to be left with just the orthogonal part of $u_2$.  Then normalize the result.

Comment: @Bye_World could you show me how that is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply Gramm-Schmidt process to the set $\{u_1, u_2\}$.

We set $$\hat{v}_1 = u_1 = (1,0)$$ then $$v_1=\hat{v}_1/||\hat{v}_1|| = (1,0)$$
Now set $$\hat{v}_2=u_2-<u_2,v_1>v_1 = (1,-1) - 1\cdot(1,0) = (0,-1)$$ then $$v_2=\hat{v}_2/||\hat{v}_2|| = (0,-1)$$ So the vectors you're looking for are $$\{v_1,v_2\}= \{(1,0),(0,-1)\}$$